# How do I set a starting point for fread?

Tags: c, fread, stdio, fseek

I'm trying to use `fseek` and `fread` to copy bytes 0x0100-0x3FFF of a binary file (Game Boy ROM) to bytes 0x0100-0x3FFF of my emulated addressSpace; however I don't know how to use `fread` to start writing to a specific byte in addressSpace. This is the code that's affected; it starts reading at 0x0100 of the ROM as expected but it writes to 0x0000-0x3EFF of addressSpace, and my question is, how can I get fread to start writing at 0x0100 instead?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t addressSpace[0x10000];

int main()
{
    FILE* gameROM = fopen("rom.gb", "rb");
    if (gameROM == NULL || sizeof(addressSpace[0]) != 1)
    {
        printf("Error");
        getchar();
        fclose(gameROM);
        return 1;
    }
    fseek(gameROM, 0x100, SEEK_SET);
    fread(addressSpace, sizeof(addressSpace[0]), 0x3EFF, gameROM);
    printf("\n%X\n", addressSpace[0x100]);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//                     v-- here
fread(addressSpace + 0x100, sizeof(addressSpace[0]), 0x3EFF, gameROM);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both answers posted were exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
fread(addressSpace+loc, sizeof(addressSpace[0]), 0x3EFF, gameROM);
```

`loc` is from where you want to write to `addressspace`

```
loc = 0x0100
```